# Is there a general way to force certain data types when importing csv data to sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, import

I have a CSV file with mixed data and I'm trying to import it to an existing SQLite database. I have two applications to manage databases (one within my GIS software and an open source one called DB Browser), but in both the imported table simply has all the fields set as the 'text' data type, even though some of them contain only numbers. Occasionally I've managed to import a DBF where the column header specifies the data type, but even then it casts everything as 'integer' when I really need it to be 'real' (because bizarrely SQL can't do maths with integers properly).

Given that the same has happened with both my applications, I'm presuming the problem lies with the SQL importing method itself. Is there anything I can do by way of preparing the CSV file, or within SQL to force the fields into the right data type?

Comment: Create a table with the appropriate column names and affinities, and then import into it. The second case described in https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have the sqlite command line tool specified in the tutorial you linked and the '.mode' and '.import' functions are not recognised by either of my sqlite applications. Is that the only way?

Comment: I think it's a better tool than some random third party app for this sort of thing.

Comment: Anyways, another possibility is to import into a temp table, and then `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` into the real table from it. Sqlite will convert text values to other types if possible to match the column affinities of the destination table.

Comment: Yes, I've downloaded it but can't get it to open any of my databases '.open FILENAME' just gives a new line, but doesn't recognise any of the tables. There's no confirmation, no list, no file browser, no cut and paste (to make sure the address is right or avoid having to type long queries out. I'm not sure I'm seeing how it's "better" yet, but maybe in time...

Comment: @Shawn Just tried your second suggestion and it works a treat, thanks very much.